# My custom Form.item component cannot retrieve the FormContext set by From

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
<Form
  labelCol={{ style: { width: 100 } }}
>
  <MyFormItem>
     <Input />
   </MyFormItem>
</Form>


import React from 'react';
import { Form, FormItemProps } from 'antd';
import { FormContext } from 'antd/lib/form/context';

const MyFormItem: React.FC<Props & FormItemProps> = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const data = React.useContext(FormContext);

  console.log(data.labelCol);

  return <Form.Item {...rest}>{children}</Form.Item>;
};
```

I expected the labelCol set by the From component to be in the data, but I couldn't get it. Looking at the source code, the Form component provides the FormContext

Answer (score 0):

import { FormContext } from 'antd/es/form/context';

I quoted the wrong context.